# Synchronize Phabricator repo with Github

Tags: git, github, phabricator

I'm using Phabricator in order to manage a project. Thus I have several repos, hosted on a personnal server, on Phabricator. I push (or arc diff) directly in them in order to have information on Phabricator.

However this project is opensource, thus I would like to host it on my Github profile at the same time. Indeed I don't want to be able to push directly from the Github repo, I just need to have a synchronized copy of the Phabricator repo on Github to let the community see the project.

I have searched on the Internet and in the Git doc, however I still don't have a working solution.
For instance, I have tried the following, but without success:

- create a repo on Github
- clone a bare repo of my phabricator repo on my computer
- in this bare repo, add the remote github repo

I'm able to push via this repo to Github, but any change on Phabricator does not appear with "git fetch" ...

Do you have any idea, or a working solution ? Thanks :)

Comment: I believe you can have two remote repos set in your machine and set a hook to commit it on Github whenever you commit in your server. You can see this [hook documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 1):

If you want Phabricator to host the master, you can add a URI with IO type of **Mirror** for your github repository under <kbd>Manage Repository</kbd> / <kbd>URIs</kbd> / <kbd>Add New URI</kbd>.

Phabricator will then automatically push to the mirror when new changes are committed.  You will need to be careful with access to the GitHub repository though - if anyone pushes to GitHub, the changes will be lost, so if possible it should be read-only except for the user that Phabricator is authenticating as.